# Google-Maps v3: How to change the map style based on zoom level?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the new Google Maps v3 STYLED MAP.

I want to change how the map is Styled based on the zoom level.

I have the following pseudo-code, how do change my map-style based on the zoom level?

```
var myOptions = { 
        zoom:      zoom, 
        center:    latlng, 
        disableDefaultUI: true, 
        navigationControl: true, 
        scrollwheel: false, 
        navigationControlOptions: {style: 
google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL,position: 
google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT}, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
}; 

var mapStyleZoomedOut = [{      featureType: "landscape", 
                                                    elementType: "all", 
                                                    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] 
                                                }]; 
var mapStyleZoomedIn = [{       featureType: "landscape", 
                                                    elementType: "all", 
                                                    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] 
                                                  },{ 
                                                    featureType: "poi", 
                                                    elementType: "all", 
                                                    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] 
                                                  }]; 
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("find-map"), 
myOptions); 
var styledMapOptions = {map: map}; 
var styleMapType =  new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyle, 
mapStyleZoomedOut); 
map.mapTypes.set('minimial', styleMapType); 
map.setMapTypeId('minimial'); 
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() { 
        // === IF Zoom Level <= 8 use mapStyleZoomedIn 
        // === If Zoom Level > 8 use mapStyleZoomedOut 
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the [Google maps API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html), I put together a test example from your source code (with actual values in order to make the test work).

Below is the code I used to test successfully, the main code to pay attention to is in the start() function.

```
var myOptions = { 
        zoom: 7, 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(1,1), 
        disableDefaultUI: true, 
        navigationControl: true, 
        scrollwheel: false, 
        navigationControlOptions: {style: 'SMALL',position: 'TOP_RIGHT'}, 
        mapTypeId: 'ROADMAP'
}; 

var mapStyleZoomedOut = [{      featureType: "landscape", 
                                                    elementType: "all", 
                                                    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] 
                                                }]; 
var mapStyleZoomedIn = [{       featureType: "landscape", 
                                                    elementType: "all", 
                                                    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] 
                                                  },{ 
                                                    featureType: "poi", 
                                                    elementType: "all", 
                                                    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] 
                                                  }];
function start()
{
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("find-map"), myOptions); 
  var styledMapOptions = {map: map, name: 'minimial'}; 
  var styledMapOptions2 = {map: map, name: 'maximial'}; 

  var sMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyleZoomedOut,styledMapOptions); 
  map.mapTypes.set('minimal', sMapType); 
  map.setMapTypeId('minimal'); 

  var sMapType2 = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyleZoomedIn,styledMapOptions2); 
  map.mapTypes.set('maximial', sMapType2);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function()
  { 
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    //DEBUG alert(zoomLevel+', '+map.getMapTypeId());
    var sMapType;
    // === IF Zoom Level <= 8 use mapStyleZoomedIn 
    if(zoomLevel <=8)
      map.setMapTypeId('maximial');
    // === If Zoom Level > 8 use mapStyleZoomedOut 
    else
      map.setMapTypeId('minimal'); 
  });
}

if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", start);
```

Comment: What are the last 4 lines for? I used your answer in a map and it worked without them anyway.

Comment: The last four lines just tell the page to run the start function when the window has loaded (First two for modern browsers, second to for older IE versions). They aren't needed if you are triggering the function in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Simple function that goes to satellite when user is zoomed in, road map when zoomed out

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() >= 15) {
        map.setMapTypeId('satellite');
    }
    else {
        map.setMapTypeId('roadmap');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by @staticbeast solution and did some refactorings.

```
map.mapTypes.set('maximal', new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyleZoomedIn, {map: map, name: 'maximal'}));
map.mapTypes.set('minimal', new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyleZoomedOut, {map: map, name: 'minimal'}));
map.setMapTypeId('minimal');

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  if (map.getMapTypeId() !== 'satellite') {
    map.setMapTypeId(map.getZoom() <= 8 ? 'min' : 'max');
  }
});
```