# How to customize Google Maps with only continent labels?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I was wondering if it is possible to create this with Google Maps:

[image]

It's a kind of travel map, with different markers. Each circle on the map represents a marker and these are clickable and linked to a specific content page. Than for each continent, there is a big typo of that continent.

I know you can customize Google Maps to your needs, but I don't know if this, what the image shows, is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. It's just a matter of styling different geographic objects. The circles can be represented as markers styled with differents images. The labels are just normal labels (you can position them at the coordinates that you want) with different styling. And the dotted arcs, are just arcs between two points.

Answer (score 0):

you should try markers with info windows :)

all you need is to create the map, and customize markers+ content.
here's an example of map with markers:
[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple)

just set the -icon- property to the png of the icon in your example

and for the content of the window, you can use an info window that will contain the advertisement you want. [example for that](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)

(in your case you want to link it to some page, maybe try an iframe with src set to the content page you want.

Comment: Is there a way to show always and only the continent names on the map? Standard it will only visible when you zoom totally out the map

Comment: yes, there is a way. you can create styled maps, and thus add properties to how the map is shown. I know you must be tired of my links :) but its faster than trying to type all this code here. look at this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#creating_a_styledmaptype. i think that you may try changing the opacity of the map such that only those grey shaped will be shown, and then add those labels

Comment: as for the lines and labels, like the other answer here mentioned, there is the option of drawing on the map and putting labels. you can find a full documentation of that in the api with many examples.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Only I don't know how to show only the continent labels at a specific zoom level. Can you help me with that?

Comment: well, i see here someone who answered something similar to what you are asking. what you want is to change the map styling according to zoom. you can do that with the 'zoom_changed' event, and then customize the map style as described in the other links. here's the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121400/google-maps-v3-how-to-change-the-map-style-based-on-zoom-level hope it helps

Comment: Google will change automatically new labels, while zooming more in on the map. But I don't know how I can change it, from when the continents should be displayed and, when you can see the country names of each state..